# Angular2 Not Recognizing component From Imported Module

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-components

I'm playing around with Angular2, and trying to have one module (`BreadcrumbDemoModule`) import the component of another (`BreadcrumbModule`).

Currently, BreadcrumbModule contains only one component: `ng2-breadcrumb`. However when I try to use this componentin `BreadcrumbDemoModule`, I get the error message:

> 'ng2-breadcrumb' is not a known element.

I think I must be missing a line somewhere, and was hoping someone could point out to me what it is that I'm doing wrong.

Thank you very much in advance!

**Files for BreadcrumbModule**

breadcrumb.component.html:

```
THIS IS A BREADCRUMB TEST
```

breadcrumb.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';  

@Component({
  selector: 'ng2-breadcrumb',
  template: require('./breadcrumb.component.html')
})
export class BreadcrumbComponent {}
```

components/breadcrumb/index.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BreadcrumbComponent } from './breadcrumb.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule //for later use
  ],
  declarations: [
    BreadcrumbComponent
  ]
})
export class BreadcrumbModule {}
```

**Files for BreadcrumbDemoModule**

breadcrumb-demo.component.html:

```
<ng2-breadcrumb></ng2-breadcrumb>
```

breadcrumb-demo.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { BreadcrumbModule } from './../index';

@Component({
  selector: 'ng2-breadcrumb-demo',
  template: require('./breadcrumb-demo.component.html')
})
export class BreadcrumbDemoComponent {}
```

components/breadcrumb/demo/index.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BreadcrumbModule } from './../index';
import { BreadcrumbDemoComponent } from './breadcrumb-demo.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BreadcrumbModule,
    BrowserModule,
  ],
  declarations: [
    BreadcrumbDemoComponent
  ]
})
export class BreadcrumbDemoModule {}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You have to add the `BreadcrumbComponent` to the exports array, and only import the `CommonModule`. You can only import the BrowserModule once in your app (usually at the bootstrap module):

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    BreadcrumbComponent
  ],
  exports: [
    BreadcrumbComponent
  ]
})
export class BreadcrumbModule {}
```

Things inside the `declarations` array are components/directives/pipes used within the module itself. If you want to expose these to other modules importing your module, then they should be added to the `exports` array

Comment: Thank you! I knew I was missing something obvious. This is what I get for looking at tutorial examples instead of referencing the API documentation directly.

Comment: The best tutorials and guides you find at [angular.io](https://angular.io), coincidentally also the same place where you can find the API ;)

Comment: Also don't forget to add to declarations the component you are using the exported from !!